# How can I add a decorator image on top of my image view

Tags: android

I have an `ImageView` in my android layout. And I would like to add a 'decorator' image at the lower right corner of my image view.
Can you tell me how can I do it?

I am thinking of doing with a FramLayout with 2 image views as its child, but how can i make one image the lower right corner of another?

```
<FrameLayout>
   <ImageView .../>
   <ImageView .../>
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to be using a `RelativeLayout` ([Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html)) instead - it supports stacking views, and all you'd have to do is align the bottom and left of the overlay `ImageView` with the bottom and left.

Comment: So is this method better or creating my own ImageView?

Comment: It depends on what you're trying to do. The method Fedor describes is slightly more resource-friendly and scalable, so if you're going to be doing this to hundreds of images or something you probably want his method. The method I describe is simpler to implement in XML and basic layout code.

Answer (score 1):

You could create your own class that extends ImageView. It will always draw decorator over the ImageView content.

```
public class MyImage extends ImageView {

    static Bitmap decorator;

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        if(decorator==null)
            decorator = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.decorator);
        canvas.drawBitmap(decorator, 0, 0, null);
    }

    public MyImage(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MyImage(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public MyImage(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int params) {
        super(context, attrs, params); 
    }
}
```